# Notepad++ resets display language

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, language, localization, regional-settings

I want to use "Englisch (customizable)", but it resets to "English" every time I start Notepad++.

Setting the language after starting as admin doesn't help. Starting as admin afterwards also doesn't help.
`config.xml` doesn't contain the word "English".
I have no other languages installed.
Notepad++ is the 32bit version on a 64bit Windows 7 (required by a plugin).

How can I make Notepad++ remember the localization setting?

Comment: FWIW no repro using Notepad 7.44 on Windows 7, 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: Notepad++ is a bit stubborn with actually customising its language file, so I changed `english.xml`, `english_customizable.xml` and `nativeLang.xml`, because different strings come from different ones of these files, even though they are included in all of them.

But while copying the content of one of the files to the others, I also copied the "`filename="english.xml"`" part, which made it switch to English. Changing that to the correct file names fixed it.

Comment: I wonder if entering file name B into file A and file name C into file B would make it switch from A to C. I also wonder if I can make Notepad++ hang/crash from that. I won't try it, but if someone wants to, have fun!